# How can I return multiple actions from a nested rxjs operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm having trouble dispatching multiple actions in the following effect:

```
    @Effect()
    someEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(someAction: Actions),
      mergeMap(
        (action)=>{
          return this.authService.getProfile(action.payload.authInfo).pipe(
              map((response: any) => {

                  if (response.isErrorResponse) {
                    return new HeaderActions.AuthFail(response);
                  } else {

                 //here i'd like to return multiple actions
                    return [
                      new HeaderActions.FetchMPInfoSuccess(this.fetchMpInfoSuccesState(getMpProfileResponse)),
                      new HeaderActions.GetAccountStates(true)
                  ]
                  }
              }),
              catchError((error:HttpErrorResponse )=>{
                return of(new HeaderActions.AuthFail(response));
              })
            );
        }
      )
    );
```

I've tried adding an array of actions, in the return block, but that's giving an error that im not sending a valid action, any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `that's not working` ← See ["It's not working" is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/), specifically point 3 and 4.

Comment: 1. `if (response.isErrorResponse)` ← that should not have to be checked here, make sure you are building restful APIs that return error status codes on failure. 2. The additional actions you want to execute should not be started in `map`, use switchMap instead and you can execute the actions simultaneously using `forkJoin`

Comment: can you provide that as an answer so I can give it a try?

Comment: You can take the parts of my comment and search on them and try to alter your code accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ***switchMap*** instead of ***mergeMap***.
Then use ***flatMap*** or ***switchMap*** instead of ***map***.

The code should be like this:

```
@Effect()
someEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(someAction: Actions),
  switchMap(
    (action)=>{
      return this.authService.getProfile(action.payload.authInfo).pipe(
          flatMap((response: any) => {

              if (response.isErrorResponse) {
                return new HeaderActions.AuthFail(response);
              } else {

             //here i'd like to return multiple actions
                return [
                  new HeaderActions.FetchMPInfoSuccess(this.fetchMpInfoSuccesState(getMpProfileResponse)),
                  new HeaderActions.GetAccountStates(true)
              ]
              }
          }),
          catchError((error:HttpErrorResponse )=>{
            return of(new HeaderActions.AuthFail(response));
          })
        );
    }
  )
);
```

To access data in your child component you can use this approach with @Input() set stuff:

```
@Input() set(data: any) {
if (data) { console.log(data) }}
```

The data in html will be there always.

**Map** modifies each item emitted by a source Observable and emits the modified item.

**FlatMap**, **SwitchMap** also applies a function on each emitted item but instead of returning the modified item, it returns the Observable itself which can emit data again.

**FlatMap** merge items emitted by multiple Observables and returns a single Observable.

**SwitchMap** is a bit different from FlatMap. SwitchMap unsubscribes from the previous source Observable whenever new item started emitting, thus always emitting the items from current Observable.

If you would like to know more about rxjs operators, please have a look [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
@Effect()
    someEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(someAction: Actions),
      switchMap(
        (action)=>{
          return this.authService.getProfile(action.payload.authInfo).pipe(
              map((response: any) => {

                  if (response.isErrorResponse) {
                    return [new HeaderActions.AuthFail(response)];
                  } else {

                 //here i'd like to return multiple actions
                    return [
                      new HeaderActions.FetchMPInfoSuccess(this.fetchMpInfoSuccesState(getMpProfileResponse)),
                      new HeaderActions.GetAccountStates(true)
                  ]
                  }
              }),
              catchError((error:HttpErrorResponse )=>{
                return of(new HeaderActions.AuthFail(response));
              })
            );
        }
      )
    );
```

So basically What I did was, instead of using a `mergeMap` before the service call, I swapped it back to simple `switchMap`.

Reason why I changed it from `mergeMap` was: you are only returning value from a single stream.